# "dpkg -l" receives shell wildcard character?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

In a bash shell where I have globbing enabled if I execute `ls -l *ou*`, then shell should pass `out.dot` and `out.png` as arguments to `ls`, i.e. `ls` never sees the `*` character. However, looks like in case of `dpkg -l *bridge*` the `dpkg` actually receives the `*`(wild-card) character:

```
root@host-machine:~# ls -l *ou*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8985 Jan 21 11:58 out.dot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 892260 Jan 21 11:58 out.png
root@host-machine:~# dpkg -l *bridge*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                          Version                             Architecture                        Description
+++-=============================================================-===================================-===================================-================================================================================================================================
ii  bridge-utils                                                  1.5-6                               amd64                               Utilities for configuring the Linux Ethernet bridge
un  cli-uno-bridge                                                <none>                                                                  (no description available)
ii  libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64                                      2.5.3-2                             amd64                               AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - shared library
root@host-machine:~#
```

Or how to explain this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing matches the pattern you specified (`*ou*`) then that is passed unexpanded to the command:

```
$ echo *ou*
*ou*
```

Answer (score 2):

The wildcards are left as is if there are no file matches. If you try:

```
dpkg -l *ou*
```

You should get:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching out.dot
dpkg-query: no packages found matching out.png
```

Use

```
dpkg -l \*ou\*
```

or

```
dpkg -l '*ou*'
```